# orika - one-way mapping

Tags: java, orika

I'm trying to get one-way mapping work at class level.

I have 2 classmaps as below:

```
mapperFactory.classMap(A.class,B.class).toClassMap()

mapperFactory.classMap(B.class,A.class).toClassMap()
```

These classmaps cannot work for bidirectional mapping. So, I'm using 2 different mappings. But using two different classmaps with bi-directional mapping is making none of the above to work. I'm looking for a way to use a classmap only for one-way mapping so that I can use both of the above.

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you please explain better your need may be there is a simpler solution, Cheers

Answer (score 0):

In Orika they will be considered the same class map (look at the MapperKey class [A,B] <=> [B,A]), you can have different direction on field level within the same class map definition.

To answer your question (If I understand) you should use two MapperFactory.

Like aToBMapperFactory and bToAMapperFactory so you can have different class map definition for each direction (as I said within a single mapper factory is not possible)